# How to spread two column dataframe with creating a unique identifier?

Tags: r, tidyr

Trying to spread two column data to a format where there will be some NA values.

dataframe:

`df <- data.frame(Names = c("TXT","LSL","TXT","TXT","TXT","USL","LSL"), Values = c("apple",-2,"orange","banana","pear",10,-1),stringsAsFactors = F)`

[image]

If a row includes `TXT` following rows that has `LSL` or `USL` will belong to that row.

For ex:

- in the first row; Name is `TXT` Value is `apple` next row is `LSL` value will be for apple's `LSL` and since no `USL` that will be `NA` until the next `TXT` name.
- If there is a `TXT` followed by another `TXT`, then `LSL` and `USL` values for that row will be `NA`

trying to create this:

[image]

I tried using spread with row numbers as unique identifier but that's not what I want:

`df %>% group_by(Names) %>%  mutate(row = row_number()) %>% spread(key = Names,value = Values)`

I guess I need to create following full table with NAs then spread but couldn't figure out how.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can expand the dataset with `complete` after creating a grouping index based on the occurence of 'TXT'

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>% 
     group_by(grp = cumsum(Names == 'TXT')) %>%
     complete(Names = unique(.$Names)) %>%
     ungroup %>% 
     spread(Names, Values) %>%
     select(TXT, LSL, USL)
# A tibble: 4 x 3
#  TXT    LSL   USL  
#  <chr>  <chr> <chr>
#1 apple  -2    <NA> 
#2 orange <NA>  <NA> 
#3 banana <NA>  <NA> 
#4 pear   -1    10
```

Answer (score 0):

In `data.table`, we can use `dcast` :

```
library(data.table)

dcast(setDT(df), cumsum(Names == 'TXT')~Names, value.var = 'Values')[, -1]

#    LSL    TXT  USL
#1:   -2  apple <NA>
#2: <NA> orange <NA>
#3: <NA> banana <NA>
#4:   -1   pear   10
```